# Unknown plugin "transform-decorators-legacy" error when using react storybook in windows

Tags: javascript, linux, windows, reactjs, babeljs

I cloned a React project created on Linux to my Windows machine.
The Project includes few react components and a storybook to test those components.
The "npm start" is configured to run the storybook at the "package.json" file:

"start": "npm run storybook"

After typing "npm start" I got this error on the browser console:

"Uncaught Error: Module build failed: ReferenceError: Unknown plugin "transform-decorators-legacy" specified in 'C:\...\node_modules\@storybo ok\ui\node_modules\react-treebeard\.babelrc'".
This is my webpack.config.js file (the problem probably comes from there):

```
module.exports = (baseConfig, env) => {
  const config = genDefaultConfig(baseConfig, env);

  config.module.rules.push({
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: [
          ['env', {
            modules: false
          }],
          'react',
          'flow'
        ],
        plugins: [
          'transform-class-properties',
          'transform-object-rest-spread',
          'flow-react-proptypes'
        ]
      }
    }
  });

  return config;
};
```

The commands runs with no errors under linux/mac. The issue only occurs with windows.

node v8.5.0
npm v5.4.2

Comment: Did you run `npm install`?

Comment: yes, the issue happens after all the required commands. (working on mac).

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue. Most are saying to make sure you exclude node_modules in your loaders section that has babel in it.

```
exclude: /node_modules/
```